# IP restriction for a folder of a web application, in IIS7

Tags: web-services, iis-7, ip, ip-restrictions

I have a web application, in which a web service resides in a folder. The whole web application can be accessed from anywhere, while the web service should only be accessed from certain IP addresses. I can't separate them and take the web service into another IIS web site, thus I need to restrict the access to the web service, while it resides in that web site. However, I have no limitation in creating **virtual directories**. What should I do? Can I do it at all?

To understand the scenario better, suppose that the domain of the website is `www.sample.com`, and every address on this website is accessible to all the Internet. For example, `www.sample.com\path1` and `www.sample.com\path2` are browsable by everyone and every IP address out there.

But the address of the web service `www.sample.com\services\user.asmx` should only be accessed from certain IP addresses, like `217.218.192.50` && `107.50.27.30` for example.

How can I achieve this configuration in IIS7?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, what a simple action it was.

Simply select the folder in IIS7, and from the right hand, select `IP Address and Domain Restrictions` (which if is not visible, must be reached via `Features View` tab).

Now, you can allow or deny any single IP address, or a range if IP addresses from seeing or not seeing your folder, and anything inside it.

Comment: I dont have that IP Address and Domain Restrictions icon in my features view or anywhere else. I heard that it is a (windows) feature that must be enabled somewhere first but I can't seem to find how or where... Any ideas?

Comment: What version of IIS you're using? I think it's a new feature. Maybe you should test with IIS7 or IIS7.5.

Comment: I'm using IIS7.5. I eventually found out that I could add this feature with the Web Platform Installer - that's usually the easiest way to add things to IIS. :)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Was there a way to do this in the web.config? For some reason I cannot do this with a folder that I am trying to restrict access to...

Comment: In case anyone else is still looking for it: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions