# How to accept requests only from the servers where the IP Address is specified inside the XML Configuration file

Tags: c#

My requirement is when i give URL and then click on ConvertToPDf button then the PDF will be opened.. I created one web service for this requirement its working fine..and my additional requirement is..

Security - It should accept requests only from the servers where the IP Address is specified inside the XML Configuration file

Method 1 - Securtiy Key | HTML URL
Method 2 - Security Key | HTML
Both Methods should return PDF .

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS IPRestriction module to secure the webservice.  This can be found on the Features tab of the item you want to secure.  It's been answered before, so instead of reinventing the wheel, please check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209369/988355

It also describes installing the IPRestriction role if you don't already have it installed.